# Javascript - Listener executing on assignment

Tags: javascript

So, I'm currently working on a HTML page that displays a table with an editable text box and a delete button for the row for every quote in a list. The list is fetched from a stored file, so I need to dynamically generate this table and its rows every time I fetch it. However, when this code runs, the table generated is empty, because when the listener is added, the delete row function executes and just removes the row right after it's added.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < quotesArray.length; i++) {
      //Insert a new row into the table.
      var newQuoteRow = quoteList.insertRow(-1);
      var cellOne = newQuoteRow.insertCell(0);
      var cellTwo = newQuoteRow.insertCell(1);

      //Insert editable text boxes for a quote into the row.
      var quoteInput = document.createElement('input');
      quoteInput.value = quotesArray[i];
      quoteInput.className = "quote";
      cellOne.appendChild(quoteInput);

      //Put a delete button at the end of the row.
      var deleteQuoteButton = document.createElement('button');
      deleteQuoteButton.innerHTML = "x";
      cellTwo.appendChild(deleteQuoteButton);
      deleteQuoteButton.addEventListener('click', deleteCurrentQuoteRow(deleteQuoteButton));
    }


  });
}

function deleteCurrentQuoteRow(buttonToDelete) {
  var currentRow = buttonToDelete.parentNode.parentNode; //get the grandparent node, which is the row containing the cell containing the button.
  currentRow.parentNode.removeChild(currentRow); //delete the row in the table
}
```

From what I understand, this problem occurs because the function linked to in the addEventListener method has a parameter, which causes it to execute immediately instead of waiting for a click. However, I can't think of a way to implement this without passing the button being clicked as the parameter, because then I won't know which row to delete. How can I fix this so that the table will actually populate, and the delete button will actually delete a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are invoking the function `deleteCurrentQuoteRow` and assigning its return value which is `undefined` as event listener.

*Use*

```
deleteQuoteButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    deleteCurrentQuoteRow(this); //Here this refers to element which invoke the event
});
```

OR, You can modify the function `deleteCurrentQuoteRow` as

```
function deleteCurrentQuoteRow() {
  var currentRow = this.parentNode.parentNode; //get the grandparent node, which is the row containing the cell containing the button.
  currentRow.parentNode.removeChild(currentRow); //delete the row in the table
}
```

Then you can just pass the function reference as

```
deleteQuoteButton.addEventListener('click', deleteCurrentQuoteRow);
```

Comment: Or just `deleteQuoteButton.addEventListener('click', deleteCurrentQuoteRow);` ? There is no need to pass the context as OP can acces it as `this` inside `deleteCurrentQuoteRow`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was overthinking this a bit too much ;-;